# Get exception error running binary file in java

Tags: java

How to get error message when execution binary file with `Runtime`?

My code is:

```
Runtime localRuntime = Runtime.getRuntime();
String strExec = "myBinary -s -a myconfigbinary.conf";
try {
    localRuntime.exec(strExec);
    System.out.println("Success execute."); 
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage().toString());      
}
```

My code is above, I only get the exception error when the file does not exist. but if I run using the console on the computer when it did not work because of the error in the configuration file or whatever is causing the binary is not running, but I still get message `Success execute.`.

My question is i want to get error message like when i get an error on the console on the computer. How to use the correct exception in this case?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the error stream like

```
Process process=localRuntime.exec(strExec);
process.waitFor();
InputStream errorStream = process.getErrorStream();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should also capture the `ErrorStream` of the process in `java`, as

```
try {
   Process proc = localRuntime.exec(strExec);
   InputStream stderr = proc.getErrorStream();
   InputStreamReader is = new InputStreamReader(stderr);
   BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(is);
   String line = null;
   while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null)
          System.out.println(line);
   int exitVal = proc.waitFor();
   System.out.println("Process exitValue: " + exitVal);
} catch (Throwable t) {
    t.printStackTrace();
}
```

If the error from the exec'd process goes to `stdout`, you might need to do the above for stdout as well.

Comment: get stack and no load view in line proc.waitFor();